# SELECT COUNT(*) returns 1 even if the request should return 0

Tags: php, sql, count

When I'm trying to get the number of rows on a SQL request and if not, the connection that follow fails. 
But in any case (also if the request should return 0), it returns 1.
Here's my code :

```
$str = 'SELECT count(*) FROM admins WHERE mail = ? AND mdp = ?';
$arr = array($mail, $pass);
$rqt = sendRqt($str, $arr);
$tab = $rqt->fetchColumn();
$cnt = count($tab);
echo $cnt;
```

I don't understand why there's no time it returns 0

Comment: Try: `print_r($tab);`. You are using `count` in query itself. You don't need to use `count` in `PHP` again.

Comment: It doesn't do anything :/ it does not show the tab content

Comment: as your statement return one column and you count the column $cnt = count($tab) it always return 1

Comment: fetchColumn returns the column value, not an array.  Look up what count() in PHP does.

Comment: @Orionss, don't change the code after you post the question.  You completely changed the question by doing so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the use of the php function `count()`.

You already have the correct number in your `$tab` variable as a string (probably, depends on php configuration / version) so you can `echo` it or cast it to an integer to make sure it is a number.

However, in php:

```
count(0) === 1
count('0') === 1
```

See [here](https://eval.in/644739) for example.

You should remove `count($tab)`.

Comment: I don't use count() anymore, but it doesn't return anything now

Comment: @Orionss You already had the number available in the `$tab` variable in your original code.

Answer (score 0):

the SQL "COUNT(*)" allways returns a row with the count (quantity) of values, so if you apply the php count() function, always will return 1 because there is one row that contains the value of the COUNT sql function

Comment: I don't use count() anymore and it doesn't return anything now

Comment: ok, if you call "var_dump($tab)" it must print the array of the SQL call, if there is none, then there is something wrong with the SQL

Comment: It returns  array(0) { }

Comment: is an empty array, it means that the fetchAll() function is not returning any row, so, there is no row matching your where conditions

Comment: I understood this but I can't see why.

Answer (score -2):

`I believe COUNT() needs a column name.`WRONG!!   count(*) should count all rows, but I still reccomend a column name like `id` or something.  You could also use an `AS` to make life a little easier

```
$str = 'SELECT count(`COLUMNNAME`) AS cnt FROM table WHERE ....
```

Comment: Now it returns 0 in any time ! But if delete the AS cnt it returns 1 as usual

Comment: Specifying a column name for this purpose actually slows down the query.  `COUNT(*)` or `COUNT(1)` (which are equivalent) is the quickest way to count the rows.